# (NetcfgInvalidSubnet) Subnet 'mySubnet' is not valid in virtual network 'myVnet'

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have a weird issue while trying to create an `azure` container instance referencing an existing virtual network and subnet.
For that I am using the following command describes in microsoft docuementation running from azure CLI:

az container create

```
--name mycontainer   --resource-group myresourcegroup  --image crazlabjira01.azurecr.io/jira-servicemanagement:4.19.0 --vnet **myVnet** --vnet-address-prefix 172.27.0.0/16 --subnet **mySubnet** --subnet-address-prefix 172.27.14.0/24
```

My subnet is in the range of the Vnet so why does the command returns the following error :

> **(NetcfgInvalidSubnet) Subnet 'mySubnet' is not valid in virtual network 'myVnet'**

Please note that if I create that container using the UI and network defined above, it works without any trouble

Thanks for help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested in my environment and it is working fine for me.

```
az container create --name myconatainer98044 -g v-ra****-***tr**e --image mycontainer7723.azurecr.io/atlassian/jira-servicemanagement:latest --vnet RG-VNET --vnet-address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet TestSubnet --subnet-address-prefix 10.0.1.0/24
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

When you create a virtual network you can configure the address space.  By default, I was given an address space of 10.0.0.0/16 which allows addresses from 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.255.255.

By changing the subnet to a valid value for a 10.0.0.0/16 address space, like 10.0.1.0/24, you will likely be successful:

For you Make Sure the subnet that you are trying to use is not being used by other resource provider. Here you might be trying to use a subnet with 172.27.14.0/24 which is already in use.

> Example : If you using a subnet for creating a SQL instance and the
> same subnet you are using for creating the Container Instance it will
> throw an error which you are getting. So Microsoft doesn’t support
> the same subnet to create a different resource provider.

In my Case my TestSubnet is delegated to `Microsoft.Containerintance`

[image]

Please refer this [document](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f1959741-abf4-4759-bf4a-2d3d11ff2e57/subnet-is-not-valid-in-virtual-network-how-to-fix?forum=azurescripting) for get the clear understanding.

Comment: Hello @RahulKumarShaw-MT, the subnet I am using is also delegated to MicrosoftContainers and it is not used by other resource. As mentionned in my post, the subnet 172.27.14.0/24, is fully valid for the vnet range based on the Ip calculation tool ( jodies.de/ipcalc). In addition if I create teh container instance manually from UI by specify same vnet and subnet, it is fully valid, what else could it be. ?

Comment: @sergecalderara. Please check this Link I have drafted the answer in step by step so there won't be any chances of mistakes . Please follow the same. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AgZg9iNUVLINk1mpJKRUI4zsVEgMybvM0y-t4x_tv80/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding a new subnet in an existing vnet in which you already have one subnet whose address space is the same as your new subnet.